# user input for triangular series of numbers

Tags: python

```
   def my_func(c=1, n=None):
    while True:
        if c > n:
            # if counter > number of iterations required
            break
        a = int(c * (c + 1)/2)
        yield a
        c += 1

my_object = my_func(n=5)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(my_object))
    except StopIteration:
        print("End of Iteration")
        break
```

Hi I have the following,basically it prints triangular numbers,What I want to do is set n = user keyboard input,bascially the user enters an iteration and it prints out triangular sequence for that number of iterations entered.

If I wanted to infinitely loop when n=None ,presumably this is when n="" ...but I'm not sure how to do that

Any help would be appreciated.

This is in python coding

error I'm getting using Seons solution

Error! Please enter a number or leave blank.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 15, in get_valid_user_input
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 20, in 
File "", line 18, in get_valid_user_input
NameError: name 'get_user_input' is not

Answer (score 0):

We start by slightly changing up my_func, where we loop infinitely if n<=-1.
We then take the user input :

- either he enters nothing (an empty string), in which case we assume he wants to loop indefinitely and set n to -1
- or he enters something else, in which case we assume he inputed an integer. We then use `int(user_input)`to convert it this value from a `str` to and `int`, and use it as the n parameter for my_func

```
def my_func(c=1, n=-1):
    while True:
        if n>-1 and c > n:
            # if counter > number of iterations required
            break
        a = int(c * (c + 1)/2)
        yield a
        c += 1

user_input = input("Enter a number, or leave blank for infinite loop: ")
if user_input == "":
    n = -1
else:
    n = int(user_input)
    
my_object = my_func(n=n)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(my_object))
    except StopIteration:
        print("End of Iteration")
        break
```

A slightly more complex version, which makes sure the user input is valid is given below. We recursively call the get_valid_user_input function until the user input is either a blank string or an integer.

```
def my_func(c=1, n=-1):
    while True:
        if n>-1 and c > n:
            # if counter > number of iterations required
            break
        a = int(c * (c + 1)/2)
        yield a
        c += 1

def get_valid_user_input():
    user_input = input("Enter a number, or leave blank for infinite loop: ")
    if user_input == "":
        return -1
    try:
        return int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error! Please enter a number or leave blank.")
        return get_valid_user_input()

my_object = my_func(n=get_valid_user_input())
while True:
    try:
        print(next(my_object))
    except StopIteration:
        print("End of Iteration")
        break
```

Comment: Why should it do the trick? Please add an explanation of what your code is fixing in OP's question.

Comment: Edited to clarify

Comment: Thanks Seon...I see where I went wrong now..:-)

Comment: What behaviour would you like when the user enters an invalid input?

Comment: a print statement maybe saying "error letter or special character entered"?

Comment: I played around with it a bit but can't seem to find a solution..maybe it's just staring me in the face.thanks

Comment: See my edited response above, you can use try/except blocks to capture the ValueError that occurs if the input cannot be converted to an int. 
Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you feel like it solved your problem :)

Comment: Weird, the except block should be catching the ValueError in the example above... not quite sure what's going on here.

Comment: I posted the full error in my original post...i tested the code using an online editor as pycharm isn't working right now for some reason..but thanks for your time Seon

Comment: Found the error - I'd made a slight typo in the code (where I wrote `get_user_input` instead of `get_valid_user_input`) which I quickly edited out. You must be running the old version. Try copy-pasting the code again, and it should now all work.

Comment: Thanks for all your time

Comment: Although the question was answered if for example I wanted to prompt the user after 10 iterations with yes or no to continue to loop indefinitely if yes is entered do an infinite loop or no to stop the loop..how would I implement that?

Comment: You could use the c variable to check when 10 iterations are reached, and use an input() statement to get the user input. Depending on the answer, a break statement could exit the while loop, or you could set n to -1 if you want to continue forever.

Comment: You probably ought to open a new question for that, as we're steering off-topic.

Comment: I still don't know how to iterate the first 10 iterations and present the user with an option to continue the infinite loop if Yes is selected or No break loop and return the option to select how many iterations the user would like